# Do Bardock and King Vegeta make appearances in Otherworld?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

This is a two part question:

1. If Bardock and King Vegeta are dead, do they ever make appearances in HFIL or Upper World? One would think that either Goku or Vegeta would want to pay their fathers a visit.
2. Do Goku or Vegeta ever mention their fathers once during the entire anime?

I don't recall any of this. Feel free to include the manga if anyone has that much knowledge on the matter.

Comment: I don't remember about Goku or Vegeta, but Raditz definitely mentions Bardock. He says something about Goku looking like their father.

Comment: I don't think Goku knew that much about his father, growing up with his grandfather since he was young

Comment: Yeah but that's what I'm saying, Goku called him Grandpa Gohan, implying he knew it wasn't his father, so he never thought to question this at one point

Comment: @userFace Goku called Gohan "Grandpa" because that's what Gohan told him he was. AFAIK, Goku never gave a thought about who his father was. He isn't the most philosophical reflexive guy, you know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anime and GT series make a lot of confusion with its fillers, but in the manga, Piccolo explains water-clear to Vegeta.

Evil souls are cleaned, their memories wiped, and then reincarnated.

Both King Vegeta and Bardock, although heroic, are clearly evil, so they are impossible to visit.

Goku never shows interest for knowing about his father. He was raised by humans, and he consider his adoptive grandfather as his true ancestor.

Please, also notice that HFIL is an invention of the American dub, which you should avoid if you are really interested in Dragonball canon. Where Goku goes is called the Other World, and what is written on the otherworld's demons' shirts is "HELL".

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an episode where vegeta has a dream about his father telling him about his royal blood an sayian ancestors.. Also I think there's an episode where bardock has a vision of goku defeating frieza but I dont think goku ever mentioned anything about his father I do remember vegeta telling goku something about his father bardock said he wasn't the best fighter but a brilliant scientist

Comment: Can you cite the episode numbers?